# PDF-Kit for Flutter

Tags: swift, flutter, pdf, pdf-viewer

in Swift there is PDFKit which allows you to display and modify PDF files, including live updates such as inserting annotations. Unfortunately, Flutter does not have a similar library that provides all of these features. Do you have any recommendations for me? I want to create a desktop application with Flutter where I can load a PDF file, select text, and mark the selected text with annotations. Thank you.

I have already used Syncfusion, but it's strange. Either I can use the PDFViewer or the PDF library, but not both together. This is different with PDFKit in Swift.